# Mysql service - Not starting

Tags: mysql, apparmor

Im a newbie to Ubuntu and I found the mysql is down without any update. Below is command I use and it results. Any reference or advice is highly appreciated.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

.

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service


mysql.service - MySQL Community Server    Loaded: loaded
(/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Fri
2017-07-21 11:23:25 SGT; 28s ago   Process: 20362
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process:
20353 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 20362 (code=exited,
status=1/FAILURE);         : 20363 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2    Memory: 324.0K
      CPU: 125ms    CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─20363 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─20425 sleep 1

Jul 21 11:23:25 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community
Server... Jul 21 11:23:25 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: mysql.service:
Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

.

```
sudo journalctl -xe
Jul 21 11:25:23 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T vmusr[1814]: [ warning] [vmusr] Error in the RPC receive loop: RpcIn: Unable to send.
Jul 21 11:25:24 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T vmusr[1814]: [ warning] [vmusr] Error in the RPC receive loop: RpcIn: Unable to send.
Jul 21 11:25:25 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T vmusr[1814]: [ warning] [vmusr] Error in the RPC receive loop: RpcIn: Unable to send.
Jul 21 11:25:26 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T vmusr[1814]: [ warning] [vmusr] Error in the RPC receive loop: RpcIn: Unable to send.
Jul 21 11:25:27 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 21 11:25:27 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 21 11:25:27 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 21 11:25:27 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T vmusr[1814]: [ warning] [vmusr] Error in the RPC receive loop: RpcIn: Unable to send.
Jul 21 11:25:27 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 21 11:25:27 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 21 11:25:27 S2PTDEVWAVEQA01T systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
```

Comment: Are you running this in a virtual machine, and what version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, VMWare are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this temporary fix:

1. Open this file `/etc/vmware-tools/tools.conf`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/vmware-tools/tools.conf
   ```
2. Add the following lines to it:

   ```
   [logging]
   vmusr.level = error
   vmsvc.level = error
   ```
3. Restart vmware services with:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart vmware
   ```
4. Restart mysql service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart mysql

   #OR --> for Ubuntu 14.04

   sudo service mysql restart
   ```

Source:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2036350